# js form submit is not working

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to submit a form, but the values are always empty.

my HTML:

```
     <form novalidate name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_MERCHANT" value="{{credit.data.merchantId}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TIMESTAMP" value="{{credit.data.currentGMTTimestamp}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TYPE" value="{{credit.data.epsType}}">

            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="credit.save()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and my js part:

```
function save(){
    document.getElementById("creditCardForm").setAttribute("action", this.data.crnUrl)
    document.forms["creditCardForm"].submit()
}
```

and from inspection, these fields all have values

[image]

but from the request, these fields are all empty:

[image]

---

update my question:
because this is a special form post that it will call NAB bank api to verify something, so I cannot put each fields into an object and do a ajax/$resource/$http call.
thanks

Comment: use ng-form instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Comment: You want to call `credit.save` method of controller to submit a form? or you wanted to directly submit a form?

Comment: I am not sure the way you are working is correct. If you are using a form and trying to fetch the user input, Shouldn't you be binding `ng-model` to your `input` div

Comment: @PankajParkar, try to submit from controller, because I need to do some other actions

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, I don't need user input at the moment

Comment: @ram1993, do you know how to submit if I use ng-form? thanks

Comment: even if you do not want the user input, the data that you want to display in input box needs to be binded to ng-model

Comment: Assuming that you don't wish to display input boxes. I guess still you should be using `ng-model` for this purpose.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit see example it will give idea about form &  ng-submit.

Answer (score 0):

That's a not angular way to submit the form via action attribute. Use `ng-submit` form attribute and make a `$http.post` request async.

```
    <form novalidate name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" 
          ng-submit="saveCredit(creditCardForm)">

        <!-- no input hidden -->

        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And you dont need hidden inputs in this way.

Comment: how to trigger ng-submit()? and the input argument is the form name? thanks

Comment: Submit is called automatically in this case, input element values you have in scope

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question and your requirement correct. You should be using following way:

```
<form novalidate name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_MERCHANT" ng-model="credit.data.merchantId">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TIMESTAMP" ng-model="credit.data.currentGMTTimestamp">
            <input type="hidden" name="EPS_TYPE" ng-model="credit.data.epsType">

            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="credit.save(credit.data)">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is assuming that `credit` is the alias for your controller.

I have tried to keep your ways of `ng-click` to call a method on controller. However with forms in angular, you can do the same via `ng-submit` directive also.

In your controller you will have something like:

```
$scope.save = function(data){

   //use data here as you like
   //data.merchantId and other fields
}

If you are using alias form, then use:
//vm or any other name you have for your `this` instance
vm.save = function(){

   // use data here as you like
}
```

Comment: how to handle the save() function in the controller? and yes, credit is the alias name of controller

Comment: there is no handling required as such. All you need is to have a function with such name and you will get the data there

Answer (score 0):

I want to try to fix your problem. The first thing that you have to do is add `ng-model` and `ng-value` in your form. For example:

view:

```
<form novalidate name="creditCardForm" id="creditCardForm" ng-submit="save()">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="credit_card.eps_merchant" name="eps_timestamp" ng-value="{{credit.data.merchantId}}">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="credit_card.eps_timestamp" name="eps_timestamp" ng-value="{{credit.data.currentGMTTimestamp}}">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="credit_card.eps_type" name="eps_type" ng-value="{{credit.data.epsType}}">

    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For the next you can create controller. For example:
angular controller:

```
angular.module('cartApp')
.controller('AddCreditCartCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$location',
'$http',
function($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.credit_card = {};
    $scope.credit.data = {
        merchantId: 'your-merchant-id',
        currentGMTTimestamp: 'your-currentGMTTimestamp',
        epsType: 'your-epsType'
    }

    $scope.save = function () {
        $http.post('/yourUrl', {credit_card: $scope.credit_card}).then(function(res){
            // Successfully create data
        },
        function(response) {
            // Failed to create data
        });
    }
}]);
```

I hope this can help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks every body above. just want to share the root cause

I have a directive called `<credit-card></credit-card>`, and inside this directive, I have the form, with both name and id to be `creditCardForm`, so when this directive is used in several places, and in the controller I use `document.forms["creditCardForm"]`, js did not know which is the target form, and this results in empty values in the request

hope it can help someone with same problem